# Congratulations, Hagen von Eitzen! +100k !!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

The number of +100k users has increased! Why? Because of the 
[**~4000 excellent answers**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen?tab=answers) Hagen von Eitzen produced.

All the hard work paid off. Congratulations!

Comment: Hagen. Vielen dank für... ah, I give up. Thank you very much for your sharp and sometimes even brilliant answers and comments. You have been a great help for lots of people here, including me.

Comment: Congratulations. Impressively consistent high quality.

Comment: On the side note, how much time does he spend on this site? Must be a non trivial amount...

Comment: @SandeepSilwal Ahh I see you mean something like the moral saying, "greatness comes with effort"?

Comment: Congratulations, @Hagen! You've done, and continue to do, great service to MSE!

Comment: And this comes from a guy who is [sooo](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174/hagen-von-eitzen) out of math business... :) Impressive. Congratulations and thanks for all the help! (You have answered couple of my questions and I appreciate it!)

Comment: At this rate, maybe we should just start a "Congratulations, you've hit 100K" thread and just bump it every time someone makes the list.

Comment: @Willie: Or decide, collectively, that it's time to stop with this tradition. It was impressive at the beginning with Arturo setting a huge gap, and then with a few others slowly catching up. But maybe now it's time to put this habit to sleep.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Perhaps we can resume the habit when someone reaches aleph-nought?

Comment: @hardmath: That is plausible. Although I'd recommend starting with the least inaccessible cardinal instead. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I plead for stopping the tradition after... well, something like 13 years. It's not unthinkable that I am 'in' then:)

Comment: Well done! ${}{}{}$

Comment: thanks all you guys! :)

Comment: I think this is the right moment to ask: @Hagen, I've always wondered what your profile picture actually is ;-)

Comment: Very impressive!

Comment: you rock mate ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thank you all for your kind remarks!
When I reached the 100k limit a few days ago, I checked a couple of times - of course - to see if someone had arranged a surprise party here at Meta. But either I had overlooked it or this thread got created just after I had stopped looking (could be a time-zone issue). So much as explanation why I didn't express my gratitude earlier.

When reaching a milestone such as this, a bit of reflection seems to be appropriate – especially when the next similar milestone, a million rep points, appears to be way out of reach (somehow it felt like taking about ten times as long to reach this milestone compared with the 10k milestone, I must be getting old).
Looking back, I cannot help but notice that ever too often the possibility of easily earning some quick rep points from absolute beginner and homework questions made me answer way too many such questions even though they should not have been answered so directly. Then again, I often find it difficult to obfuscate a one-liner computation into a paragraph length hint.
Looking forward, first and foremost, I guess that with no nagging rep goal in sight I may calm down a bit and be more likely to refrain from answering all those rep baits. :)

I also cannot help but notice that the answers that got most awarded by the community („Great Answer“ and „Enlightened“ badges) are hardly ever the answers I take most pride in – or sometimes I cannot see how to justify such prominence over other answers to the same questions that are definitely not worse and yet somehow failed to participate in some inexplicable rep-hype.
The lesson to be learned from this is of course that reputation is not everything (or rather: reputation points are not everything).

So once again: Thank you all - I'm no good at speeches and so it is not unwelcome that I already have to step back from the speaker's desk to give room for joriki or Don Antonio in a few moments – give them a hand, folks!

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations! Thank you for your amazing and immense contributions to this site! (This much in just over an year? Impossible for me!)